# Cannot find name +'Input'. any Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get @Input to work with Typescript in Angular 2. I am getting the following error and I don't understand why.

> [ts] Cannot find name 'Input'. any

Below is the code from that component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-item',
   templateUrl: './app-item.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app-item.component.css']
})
export class AppItemComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input item; //TypeScript complains here. 

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {}
}
```

The project and component were both created using the Angular CLI. Why can't TypeScript figure out the @Input decoration?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to add this,

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Same for Output incase you are using that.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I already had:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

So, when I tried to use:

`import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';`

It didn't work.

What I had to do was import like that **(Without the word Component)**

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

And it worked just fine

Answer (score 3):

@Marcielli, it didn't work because of the double import of Component. If you change the import statement to the following

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

You would be just fine. Optionally adding the Input module in a separate import statement is perfectly fine, but you should generally stick with either importing all components from a module in one statement, or each in separate statements.